# Python парсинг сравнение библиотек

Tags: python, request, asyncio

Здравствуйте, пробую разные библиотеки для парсинга.
Сначала был такой набор: request + lxml+ concurrent.futures для многопоточности.
Количество потоков 10. Кто-то посоветовал, что можно увеличить скорость используя asyncio.
Переписал код, используя asyncio, aiohttp+lxml. Максимальное количество запросов установил для сравнения

```
sem=asyncio.Semaphore(10)
```

Может кто подсказать, почему второй способ проигрывает по времени парсингу почти в 2 раза, хотя асинхронный подход должен быть более быстрым?

```
url_select_city=["https://www.mvideo.ru/sitebuilder/blocks/regionSelection.json.jsp?pageId=homepage&pageUrl=/&"]
url_main="https://www.mvideo.ru"
sem=asyncio.Semaphore(10)

async def get_html(request):
    return lxml.html.fromstring(request)

async def request(client,url,limit):
    with(await limit):
        async with client.get(url) as r:
            print(r.status)
            return await r.text()


async def request_json(client,url):
    async with client.get(url) as r:
        return await r.json()

async def parse_city(client,url):
    try:
        r = await request_json(client,url)
        log.info('Выполнен запрос')
        html=await get_html(r["htmlContent"])
        log.info('Получен html')
        cities=[]
        form=html.cssselect('form[id="city-radio-from"]')[0]
        for elem in form.cssselect("input[class='input-radio']"):
            city = elem.get("value")
            log.info(city)
            city_temp=[]
            city_temp.append(city)
            city_temp.append("https://www.mvideo.ru/smartfony-i-svyaz/smartfony-205/f/page=" + str(1)+"?cityId="+str(city))
            cities.append(city_temp)
        log.info("Получены города")
        return cities

    except Exception as err:
        print(err)

async def parsing_first_list(client, city,limit):
    city_title=city[0] #Получение кода города
    city_url=city[1]   #Получение ссылки на 1 страницу списка телефонов данного города

    r=await request(client,city_url,limit)
    log.info("Запрос: %s",city_url)
    html = await get_html(r)

    count_list=html.xpath(".//a[@class='c-pagination__num c-btn c-btn_white ']/text()")[0]
    log.info("Количество страниц: %s",count_list)
    urls_list=[]
    for i in range(1,int(count_list)+1):
        url_temp=[]
        url_temp.append("https://www.mvideo.ru/smartfony-i-svyaz/smartfony-205/f/page=" + str(i)+"?cityId="+city_title)
        url_temp.append(city_title)
        urls_list.append(url_temp)
    log.info("Парсинг закончен:%s",city_url)
    return urls_list

async def parse_list_object(client, list_objects,limit):
        url=list_objects[0]
        city=list_objects[1]
        log.info("Парсинг list_objects: %s | %s",url, city)
        r=await request(client,url,limit)
        log.info("Запрос list: %s", city)
        html=await get_html(r)
        urls_object=[]
        for elem in html.xpath(".//div[@class='c-product-tile sel-product-tile-main ']"):
            error_div=elem.xpath(".//span[@class='c-product-label__text']")
            if(error_div!=[]):
                error_div=error_div[0]
                error_text=error_div.xpath("span[2]/text()")[0]
                if(error_text!="Витринный образец"):
                    continue
            link_object=url_main+elem.xpath(".//h4[@class='e-h4 u-pb-0']/a")[0].get("href")+"/shopdirections?cityId="+city
            url_temp=[]
            url_temp.append(link_object)
            url_temp.append(city)
            urls_object.append(url_temp)
            log.info("Ссылка телефона: %s - страница List: %s",link_object,url)
        log.info("Спарсен  - %s",url)
        if(len(urls_object)>0):
            print("Количество спарсенных ссылок:",len(urls_object))
        else:
            urls_object=[]
        return urls_object





async def main(urls):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
        coroutines = [parse_city(client, url) for url in urls]
        completed, pending =await asyncio.wait(coroutines)
        for item in completed:
            cities=item.result()
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
        coroutines1=[parsing_first_list(client, city_url,limit=sem) for city_url in cities]
        completed, pending=await asyncio.wait(coroutines1)
        list_objects=[]
        for item in completed:
            list_objects += item.result()
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
        coroutines2=[parse_list_object(client, url_object,limit=sem) for url_object in list_objects]
        completed, pending=await asyncio.wait(coroutines2)
        url_object=[]
        for item in completed:
            item= item.result()
            url_object+=item

if __name__ == '__main__':

    log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s:%(message)s'
    logging.basicConfig(format=format, level=logging.INFO)
    log.info("Start")
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    try:
        t_start = time.time()
        # запуск цикла  обработки событий
        event_loop.run_until_complete(main(url_select_city))
        t_end = time.time()
        log.info("Time End: %s", t_end - t_start)  
    finally:
        event_loop.close()
```

Этот скрипт переходит по 1000 ссылкам и получает ссылки на 9000 объектов. На async занимает около 1200 секунд. Аналогичный скрипт на request + lxml+ concurrent.futures в 10 потоков занимает 250 секунд. Время парсинга 1 страницы: 90% отправка и получение запроса и 10% парсинг самой страницы, т.е преобладают операции I/O а не CPU-Bound. Если не указывать semaphore скорость парсинга очень быстрая, но через некоторое время выдает ошибку TimeoutError, думаю это связано с недостаточным временем для выполнения задания. Посоветуйте что нибудь

Другой код:

```
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
count_thread = 10
list_urls=[]
object_urls=[]
cities=[]
url_main="https://www.mvideo.ru"
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s:%(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

def parse_list_object(list_object):
    start = time.time()
    url=list_object[0]
    city=list_object[1]
    log.info("Парсинг list: %s",url)
    r=request(url)
    html=get_html(r)
    object=[]
    for elem in html.xpath(".//div[@class='c-product-tile sel-product-tile-main ']"):
        error_div=elem.xpath(".//span[@class='c-product-label__text']")
        if(error_div!=[]):
            error_div=error_div[0]
            error_text=error_div.xpath("span[2]/text()")[0]
            if(error_text!="Витринный образец"):
                continue
        link_object=url_main+elem.xpath(".//h4[@class='e-h4 u-pb-0']/a")[0].get("href")+"/shopdirections?cityId="+str(city)
        object.append(link_object)
        object.append(city)
        object_urls.append(object)
        log.info(link_object)
    end = time.time()
    log.info("Количество object %s",len(object_urls))
    log.info("Спарсен за %s", end-start)

def start_first_list():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(count_thread) as executor:
        for _ in executor.map(first_list, cities):
            pass

def start_parse_list_object():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(count_thread) as executor:
        for _ in executor.map(parse_list_object, list_urls):
            pass

def start_parse_object():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(count_thread) as executor:
        for _ in executor.map(parse_object, object_urls):
            pass

def request(url):
    while True:
        try:
            r=requests.get(url)
            if r.status_code != 200:
                log.info("Ошибка, Код ответа: %s", r.status_code)
                time.sleep(1)
                continue
            else:
                return r
        except Exception as e:
            log.info("Ошибка ConnectionError")
            time.sleep(1)


def request_json(url):
    while True:
        try:
            r = requests.get(url)
            if r.status_code != 200:
                log.info("Ошибка, Код ответа: %s", r.status_code)
                time.sleep(1)
                continue
            else:
                return r.json()
        except Exception as e:
            log.info("Ошибка ConnectionError")
            time.sleep(1)


def get_html(request):
    return lxml.html.fromstring(request.text)

def parse_city():
    r = request_json("https://www.mvideo.ru/sitebuilder/blocks/regionSelection.json.jsp?pageId=homepage&pageUrl=/&")
    log.info('Запрос страницы городов')
    html = lxml.html.fromstring(r["htmlContent"])
    log.info('Получение html')
    for elem in html.xpath("//input[@name='/com/mvideo/domain/RegionSelectionFormHandler.cityId']"):
        city=elem.get("value")
        if(city!=""):
            cities.append(city)
            log.info(city)

def first_list(city):
    url="https://www.mvideo.ru/smartfony-i-svyaz/smartfony-205/f/page=" + str(1)+"?cityId="+str(city)
    r = request(url)
    log.info("Переход на 1 страницу города:"+city)
    html = get_html(r)
    count_list = html.xpath("//a[@class='c-pagination__num c-btn c-btn_white ']/text()")[0]
    log.info("Парсинг list %s| %s",url,count_list)
    for i in range(1,int(count_list)+1):
        parameters=[]
        parameters.append("https://www.mvideo.ru/smartfony-i-svyaz/smartfony-205/f/page=" + str(i)+"?cityId="+str(city))
        parameters.append(city)
        list_urls.append(parameters)

def get_html_json(r):
    return lxml.html.fromstring(r)





if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_main=time.time()

    log.info('start')
    parse_city()
    start_first_list()
    start_parse_list_object()

    log.info('end')
    log.info("Время работы парсера: %s",time.time()-start_main)
```

Только что сравнил  1097c vs 196c

Comment: `асинхронный подход должен быть более быстрым` не факт, т.к. asyncio это выполнение кода в одном потоке, через карунтины

Comment: я могу себе представить случай, когда наоборот результаты. Без конкретного кода (benchmark), чересчур обширный вопрос.

Comment: @gil9red Добавил код и комментарий, посоветуйте что-нибудь

Comment: @jfs Код предоставил

Comment: с каким кодом сравнивать? Не нужно внешний сайт долбить, создайте простейший сервер для тестирования, который локально можно запустить(если только вы не думаете, что от этого результат сравнения изменится).

Comment: @jfs Добавил 2 код

Comment: @jfs, и что вы имели под простейшим сервером? локальный сервер с 1 страничкой и множеством запрос с ней из кода?

Comment: простейший сервер, который позволит benchmark запустить. Если статическая страница работает, значит достаточно статической страницы.

Comment: читая код, возможная проблема в самой первой функции `async get_html()`: на время работы останавливается весь цикл событий. Попробуйте в executor запускать (если не знаете как, то просто на фиксированный результат заменить для теста: `return html_doc`).

Comment: @jfs Не совсем понял, вы хотите, чтобы вместо return lxml.html.fromstring(request) я указал return html_doc?

Comment: @danilshik я не понимаю что не ясно

Comment: @jfs что такое html_doc? Не понимаю что за функция

Comment: представьте функция: `def f(a, b): return a+b` Когда я говорю замените на фиксированный результат, я имею в виду: `def f(a,b): return 8`. Это проверяет гипотезу оказывает ли влияние на производительность эта функция. В вашем результат ` `lxml.html.fromstring(request)` закэшируйте в `html_doc` переменной и возвращайте при последующих вызовах. Посмотрите  сколько из 1200 секунд это скосит. Это делается для теста, чтобы понять где у вас узкое место.

Comment: @jfs все понял, сейчас протестирую

Comment: если вы тесты против внешнего сайта выполняете, то о производительности тяжело говорить. Тестируйте относительно вашего собственного сервера